# OData 8: custom controller name

Tags: c#, routes, controller, odata, webapi

**ASP .NET WebApi version**: 5

**OData version**: 8.0.11

The problem:

I want to access Odata models through a controller with custom name (which is different from entity name).
Basically, I need all three identifiers (entity name, odata resource name, controller name) to be different.
PS: I tried to use RouteAttribute for the controller, but couldn't get what I wanted, since OData requires '

---

Example:

1. Entity:

```
    class Person 
    {
       ....
    }
```

2. EDM model:

```
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>(name: "CustomName1");
```

3. Controller:

```
    class CustomName2Controller : ODataController
    {
       ....
    }
```

3. Desired result:

`/odata/Person` - should invoke `CustomName2Controller` and return `Person` models

---

Is this possible?
PS: I tried to use RouteAttribute for the controller, but couldn't get what I wanted.

Also, as far as I understand, OData requires controller prefix (the part before 'Controller') to be equal the resource name ('CustomName1'). Maybe there is a way to modify this default routing behavior?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed in OData v8. You can use ODataRoute in OData v7 though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).